# Shell script to search and display line from file with 3 different options

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

i have a awk command which will store results like below, from the results i want to pass arguments and fetch my records with 3 conditions.

awk '/^E 20[0-9][0-9]/ {d=$1 FS $2 FS $3;f=1;n=NR} f && /location/$1=$1;gsub(/[<>]/,"");print n,d,$0;f=0}' OFS='|' logfile >> errorlog

input errorlog file will be like below

```
  1434887|E 2014-04-10 23:07:02.288|location=PIN_ERRLOC_PCP:2|class=PIN_ERRCLASS_SYSTEM_DET:1|errno=PIN_CONNECT_FAILED:114
1434896|E 2014-04-10 23:07:02.288|location=Unknown|pin|location:0|class=UNKNOWN:0|errno=PIN_CONNECT_FAILED:26
1434947|E 2014-04-10
```

1. if date is given as parameter (2014-04-03),it should return records matching the date.
2. if date & time, it should print lines starting from that time of that date till end of the date.
3. if given time alone is given it should return records from that time till end of file.

Comment: For case three what date should the output start from? The first date that has that time or the last date that has that time?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: for case 3 i will give just time as 23:07:02 then it shud take the system current date and fetch lines greater than or equal to 23:07:02 till the end of the file. i need shell script file plz explain the commands u using in your answers. i am new to shell.

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't about getting others to do your work for you. It's about trying to resolve programming problems, indicated by including your code in your question, along with any error msgs you're getting, output, and comments about why the output isn't meeting your requirements. Good luck.

Comment: Is your awk command correct as entered or is there a missing `{` after `/location/`?

Comment: The third case becomes the first case as soon as you get today's date. After that it is simply an appropriate grep command away. The middle case requires a bit more work but I believe awk range expressions will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you if you want to go that route. If not it gets a good bit more complicated.

Comment: @Etan Reinsner: that awk will provide a file named(errorlog) which looks like the format as in my post, i am trying to to fetch records from that resultant file(errorlog) with the constraints

Comment: That awk command is a syntax error for me, hence my question. I believe you are missing a `{` at the start of the second pattern action. (Since I don't know what `f && /location/$1=$1;` could possibly do at the pattern level otherwise.)

Comment: @Etan Reinsner:- please ignore awk coz it generates result from another file(logfile) there i am replacing <Location as blank,thats why u are getting error, i was trying to do cat errolog | sed (parameter). i want to pass this parameter to shell in command line. my problem is declaring arguments in shell script and executing it.

Comment: If you have an attempt at the script you want you should include that in your post.

Comment: Are the lines in the `errorlog` file always sorted with respect to date and time? (Earliest day comes before most recent day)

Comment: @Hakon Haegland:- Yes it is always sorted

Comment: @EtanReisner: i have updated the post with my beginner code.

Comment: You can't use shell variables inside single quoted strings (e.g. your two sed commands). You need double quotes for that.

Comment: You also need to use the `test` (or `[`) command in your `if` statements for them to work the way you expect (`if [ $2 = 0 ];`). Also empty/unset shell variables are not `0` so that test won't work if you don't actually pass `0` to your script for those positions.

Comment: @ Etan Reisner: thank you, yes iam going to pass argument as $1 $2 $3 values as 24-04-03 0 0 in this case iam passing only date and another two arguments are 0 0, if $2 and $3 are 0, i use sed -n -e "/$1/,p". if possible help me via chat id srinivas190@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following Perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.12;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::Piece;

my ($date,$time)=getOpts();

my @lines=read_file('errorlog');

if (defined $date && ! defined $time) {
    for (@lines) {
        print if $date eq @{[split(" ")]}[1];
    }
}
elsif (defined $date && defined $time) {
    for (@lines) {
        my $tmp=@{[split(/\|/)]}[1];
        my ($a,$b)=$tmp=~/E (.*?) (.*)\./;
        print if ($date eq $a && $time le $b);
    }
}
elsif (defined $time) {
    $date = localtime->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
    for (@lines) {
        my $tmp=@{[split(/\|/)]}[1];
        my ($a,$b)=$tmp=~/E (.*?) (.*)\./;
        print if ($date eq $a && $time le $b) || ($date lt $a);
    }
}

sub getOpts { 
    my $date;
    my $time;

    GetOptions (
        "date=s" => \$date,
        "time=s" => \$time
        );
    return ($date,$time);
}
```

Example run: `p.pl --date=2014-04-03 --time=15:07:15`

Comment: iam running as sriperl.pl --date=2014-04-03 but error is command not found. i have chmod to 755 to the file.

Comment: @Srini What name did you give the perl script? Maybe you could try adding a `./` in front of the script name.. Like: `./sriperl.pl --date=2014-04-03`

Comment: @ Håkon Hægland: it is executing but not showing any output. the errolog file is the present working directory.

Comment: @Srini Could you paste the error log file at pastebin.com ? Then I will try to run it on my machine..

Comment: Haegland:-i have pasted in the site with title as 'srini errorlog', i want to process the requirement from that file.

Comment: @Srini Could you give the link to the file here?

Comment: @Srini I found it. It seems to work for me. I used `p.pl --date=2014-04-03`. The output from my run is given here http://pastebin.com/FkBJerLX

Comment: @ Hakon Haegland:- will this perl script take the file from the present working directory or i should mention inside the script. i mean i have given the file name as my @lines=read_file('errorlog');

Comment: @ Hakon Haegland:- any system requirements to check for perl execution. if so let me know how to check it in my server iam connecting.

Comment: @Srini I cannot move our discussion to SO chat, since you have too low reputation. Are you on google hangouts? Then we can continue this discussion there..

Comment: yes my google id is srinivas190@gmail.com give a ping

Answer (score 0):

I have figured a solution for this with a simple shell script and its working fine

/usr/bin/env bash

input_file="input.txt"

awk '/^E/ {a=substr($0,1,24);n=NR} NR==n+2 && n {print n,a,$0}' logfile > "$input_file"

if [ $(echo $1 | wc -m ) -gt 11 -a "x${2}"=="x" ]; then
 ts=$1
else
 date=$1
 ts=$2
fi

if [ "x${ts}" != "x" -a "x${date}" != "x" ]; then

```
    grep ${date} ${input_file} | sed -n '/'"${ts}"'/,$p'
```

elif [ "x${ts}" != "x" -a "x${date}"=="x" ]; then

```
    sed -n '/'"${ts}"'/,$p' ${input_file}
```

else

```
    grep ${date} ${input_file}
```

fi